# is it possible to assign a filter to apply only on a specified material

Tags: scripting, game-engine

I found out this custom filter with a bloom effect giving a glow effect. My question is, is it possible to make the filter specific to a specific material making it the only one glowing to simulate light glow?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is. Use **material IDs** to mask certain areas of the image.
I think the manual page gives you all the information and examples you need:

https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/converter/id_mask.html

Comment: If you looked at the question properly, he is using a custom filter in the game-engine and therefore the compositor will have no effect.